# PayPal "Authorization Failed"

Tags: php, paypal

(This is the first time I've worked with the PayPal API so bear with me.)

I'm trying to create encrypted buttons on the fly using the BMCreateButton API, using slightly modified code from [this page](https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppmacole/encrypting-your-buttons-through-paypal-api-php-using-soap). Unfortunately I can't seem to get this working, as I get an "authentication/authorization failed" message in the PHP error log. (I've also asked this on the PayPal developer forum but haven't got an answer.)

This code:

```
function createButton($name, $price) {
    // Check to make sure that our version of PHP supports SOAP.
    if((PHP_VERSION_ID < 50101) || !in_array("soap", get_loaded_extensions())) {
        error_log("PHP not running with SOAP");
    } else {
        include_once("config.php"); //this file holds the credentials and whether it's running in sandbox mode or not
        //basic variable validation
        $price = floatval($price);

        // Import the PayPal WSDL.
        $location = $sandbox ? "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/" : "https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/";
        $soapClient = new SoapClient("https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl", array(
            location => $location
        ));

        // Set our API credentials.
        $credentials->Credentials->Username = $username;
        $credentials->Credentials->Password = $password;
        $credentials->Credentials->Signature = $signature;
        $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader("urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI", "RequesterCredentials", $credentials));

        // Start creating our BMCreateButtonReq object.  For full details about this object, see
        // http://tinyurl.com/3mxau6j .
        $BMCreateButtonReq->BMCreateButtonRequest->Version = "71.0";

        $BMCreateButtonReq->BMCreateButtonRequest->ButtonCode = "ENCRYPTED";

        // What type of button are we creating?
        $BMCreateButtonReq->BMCreateButtonRequest->ButtonType = "CART";

        // Specific variables for this button.  For the full list of options, see
        // http://tinyurl.com/6qyanl .  For a basic payment, these two should be enough.

        $BMCreateButtonReq->BMCreateButtonRequest->ButtonVar[] = "amount=$price";
        $BMCreateButtonReq->BMCreateButtonRequest->ButtonVar[] = "item_name=$name";

        // Run the API call.
        $response = $soapClient->BMCreateButton($BMCreateButtonReq);

        if($response->Ack == "Success" || $response->Ack == "SuccessWithWarning") {
            // If successful, the button code will be in the Website element of $response.
            // It'll be a full HTML form, so don't wrap it in any <form> tags -- just
            // display it as-is.
            echo $response->Website;
        } else {
            error_log("Could not create PayPal button. " . serialize($response->Errors));
            echo "<p class=\"note\">Cannot create button</p>";

        }
    }
}
```

gives this in the error log:

```
Could not create PayPal button. O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:12:"ShortMessage";s:35:"Authentication/Authorization Failed";s:11:"LongMessage";s:49:"You do not have permissions to make this API call";s:9:"ErrorCode";s:5:"10002";s:12:"SeverityCode";s:5:"Error";}
```

I've checked the credentials and they're correct, and fail with the sandbox as well as the live API. Am I missing something fundamental, or is there an error in the code I may have overlooked?

Comment: Not an answer as such, but I'd be tempted to give the paypal sdks on github a try.. they tend to work relatively better than some of the code kicking around in the docs and might save you one or two headaches! There's one here for the button manager api: https://github.com/paypal/buttonmanager-sdk-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember this one!

Are `$username`, `$password`, and `$signature` defined inside the function?  If not, you need to add `global $username, $password, $signature` at the top of the function.

Comment: Yup, got that issue fixed. Now getting `O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:12:"ShortMessage";s:14:"Security error";s:11:"LongMessage";s:28:"Security header is not valid";s:9:"ErrorCode";s:5:"10002";s:12:"SeverityCode";s:5:"Error";}` in the error log.

Comment: That issue was a stray space in the `$signature` variable. Buttons are now appearing!